# How can I see the result of karate print on visual studio code debug console

Tags: karate

When I try to print something in **debug console** it prints **[done]**, Instead of seeing the real result.

[image]

I can see the real result of the print on Terminal.

[image]

I don't understand why I could not see the result of the print on debug console.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some prior operation failed. Try printing parent objects:

```
print createMachine
```